# Improving execution time of Task.start()

Tags: google-earth-engine, performance, google-earth-engine-python-api

I need to export lots of images from earthengine using the Python API. I use the following code.
Here everything is pretty fast but the execution of `task.start()` take ages.

```py
satellites = {} #contain the names of the used satellites
    task_list = []
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        image, satellites[year] = getImage(sources, bands, ee_multiPolygon, year)
        
        for i, polygon in enumerate(ee_polygons):
            
            description = f"{descriptions[year]}_{i}"
        
            task_config = {
                'image':image,
                'description': description,
                'scale': pm.getScale(satellites[year]),
                'region': ee.Geometry(polygon),
                'maxPixels': 10e12
            }
            
            task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
            task.start() #this very step take ages
            task_list.append(description)
```

Is it normal ? and if yes is there a way to increase it's speed ? I don't really care about the time the images require to be downloaded to my Gdrive, my problem is that I want my end user to close the notebook when everything is launch on GEE. Unfortunately it this case it takes 30 minutes to start all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

task.start() is where Earth Engine finally does something with the computational description (also called a computation graph or a DAG) the rest of your code put together.  The execution time is related to the complexity of your DAG, plus other things like asset existence and ACL checking.  It doesn't touch any pixels or table rows, it's just doing pre-checks to ensure the task *can* be run.  If your code uses for-loops or iterate() in the process of generating the DAG, those can contribute significantly to the execution time due to parsing & expansion (so avoid them).

If you're doing something very complex to create your image and then chopping it up into pieces corresponding to each polygon (that's what this code seems to be doing), then all the costs of pre-evaluating the DAG are duplicated in every export, and there's not really any way to mitigate that cost.

It is possible to submit jobs in parallel as long as you're not trying to submit too many of them at once (don't exceed 20 at a time), however, if your regions are relatively small (less than 1M pixels), then you might not need to use the batch system at all.  Instead you might be able to use getDownloadUrl (or the getPixels REST API), and that is also something that you can do in parallel.  It might give you better overall performance, since you don't need to wait for batch jobs to start, and can skip using Google Drive.

Comment: useful link: https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26