# How can I generate a multiband tif image using getDonwloadUrl?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I use the GEE API in a Python environment and I want to upload numerous small image to my local machine. I try to implement the solution suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386406/154945). Before upgrading my code I wanted to do some test in EE code editor but I cannot make it work.

So I tried to use the ee method `getDownloadUrl` to retrieve multiband images on very small surface using the following code:

```js
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('users/bornToBeAlive/FRA_Grid_2')
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30')
  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
  .map(maskS2clouds)

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};


//clip the dataset on the aoi 
var clip = dataset.mean().clip(aoi)

// get the first tile 
Map.addLayer(clip, visualization, 'S2')
Map.addLayer(aoi.first().geometry(), {}, "france")
Map.centerObject(aoi.first())
```

The displayd image is very snowy but I manage to see things.

now to upload this image I want to get a downloadable link:

```js
var link = clip.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']).getDownloadURL({
    'name': 'toto',
    'region': aoi.first().geometry(),
    'filePerBand': false
});

print(link)
```

Unfortunately the link I get is giving me an image that is not scaled properly (the square is way too big) and I only get the same value for each pixel on each band.

Did I do something wrong? Does anyone knows how to use  this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the proposed code, you forgot the `scale` parameter.

here is a proper implementation for at 10 meters for sentinel 2 data :

```js
var link = clip.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']).getDownloadURL({
    'name': 'toto',
    'region': aoi.first().geometry(),
    'filePerBand': false,
    'scale': 10
});

print(link)
```